# How to display IEnumerable item in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have this view :

```
    @model IEnumerable<sn.Models.Order>



 <h2>

    **Name of Recipients**

 </h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
           Last Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Mark
        </th>
        <th>
           Quiz Number
        </th>
        <th>
          Pass
        </th>
        <th>
           Paid
        </th>
        <th>
           Mark Date
        </th>
     </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Customer.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mark)
        </td>
        <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuizNo)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pass)
            </td>
             <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Paid)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MarkDate)
            </td>
          </tr>
    }

</table>
```

below is an image showing my view:
[image: View]

I want to display the LastName in place of **Name of Recipients** . The item LastName does not change for a particular customer. This view is showing the details of that user and this is part of the code I used to get the results in my controller:

```
var certificateDetails = db.orders.Where(p => p.ID == id);
return View( certificateDetails.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<h2>
    @(Model.Any() ? Model.First().Customer.LastName : "")
</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am getting this error after executing the code changes you gave me: **CS0119: 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.First<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,bool>)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context** its highlight the changes in question.

Comment: I have forgotten the parentheses behind `First`. I have edited my answer